# Can one import an entire workspace into eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, import, workspace

I have searched around the interwebs and have failed to find the answer to this question so I thought I would ask the wise people here.

I reformatted my computer recently and I backed up all my data including my Eclipse workspace but I failed to export my projects using Eclipse itself. I replaced my workspace file back into Eclipse but it does not show any of my projects as run-able Eclipse projects. Is there a provision to import a whole workspace into Eclipse? Is there information in other files that Eclipse requires or will I just need to manual rebuild the project? Thanks for your help and advice all.

Comment: It's weird that simply choosing the workspace when opening Eclipse doesn't work. Workspaces are the reason I try to avoid Eclipse altogether, though. They're a pain when it comes to portability, and situations like yours.

Comment: Did you actually try to switch the workspace? `File -> Switch workspace`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to browse earlier workspace. Projects inside workspace automatically appears in project panel. However if they don't, goto File-> import menu and select "import existing" and browse to project folder in workspace. It should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can right click on the Package Explorer and select Import. There is an option called Existing projects into workspace. Select that and then select your folder. It will show importable projects. Select them all and import.

Answer (score 0):

You can open directly a Workspace created with an earlier version Eclipse. The new instance will then update the Workspace to the newer metadata configuration. This might prevent earlier Eclipse versions of opening the updated Workspace.

To deal with this I keep Workspaces of different Eclipse versions in different folders, in a structure like this:

```
Eclipse.Neon
├── Workspace.DomainA
└── Workspace.DomainB
Eclipse.Oxygen
├── Workspace.DomainX
└── Workspace.DomainY
```

If I wish to import, say, DomainA to Eclipse Oxygen I simply copy it to the `Eclipse.Oxygen` folder:

`cp -r Eclipse.Neon/Workspace.DomainA Eclipse.Oxygen/`

And then open that Workspace with Oxygen.

One final note: Workspace management is considerably easier if projects are kept outside its folder, e.g. in a general code versioning folder like `git` or `svn`.